# Route to Login screen in react native in case a user is not authenticated

Tags: react-native, routes, navigation

I've seen a lot of examples how it is done with other libraries but I'm using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) one and need a solution for it.

Here is a code example:

```
const MainTabs = TabNavigator({
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Main:  { screen: MainTabs },
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
},{
  initialRouteName: "Login",
  headerMode: "none",
});

export default RootNavigator;
```

Full app code you can find here: https://snack.expo.io/Hy8IXWppg

User authentication status is checked on my server.

I want Login screen to be rendered for a user on the app launch in case the user is not authenticated but ideally, it would be nice to route the user to Login in case his session is deleted/expired on the server.

In other words, I want to be able to do that at any time from any code part.

I know I can do this with code like below

```
if(!userIsLoggedIn()) {
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Login'}) );
}
```

inside a screen component (where `userIsLoggedIn` is my custom auth checking method), but I don't want to perform this action manually in each component. But even I wouldn't have another choice, where to put `userIsLoggedIn()` check? Inside consctructor/componentWillMount/componentWillUpdate?

**UPDATE**

I expected a solution which would allow me to specify all screens/routes which require authentication.

It seems to me that I have to use routes here with some custom rules. 
But there are two kinds of standard routers: TabRouter and StackRouter.

I'm going to have 3-level navigation

```
StackNavigator
   LoginScreen
   RegisterScreen
   AboutScreen
   FirstLevelTabNavigator
       Tab1: AccountScreen
       Tab2: SecondLevelTabNavigator
           Tab1Screen
           Tab2Screen
           Tab3Screen
```

Obviously, Login, Register and About screens don't require authentication, but on an attempt to access Account, Tab1Screen, Tab2Screen or Tab3Screen users must be redirected to LoginScreen.

Should I construct 3 routers for each navigator now?

Comment: hi gumkins, I have exactly the same usecase, did you find answers to your above questions? where to put userIsLoggedIn, and did you build custom routers?

Comment: Hi, no, I've switched to other app areas now. As a temporary solution, I'm navigating to login screen on each app launch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have another screen which would be your first screen. This can be a simple component which would just be an `ActivityIndicator`. In that you should check with your server and navigate accordingly.

Ex.
InitialComponent

```
componentWillMount() {

     getStatus(this.navigate.bind(this))
}

navigate(loggedIn) {
   this.setState({animating: false});
   if(loggedIn) {
      navigate to Main
   } else {
      navigate to Login
   }    
  }

render() {
  return(<View> <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.animating}/> </View>);

}
```

This would also have benefit of showing your user that you are processing something, before redirecting them(For example if the request takes time).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SwitchNavigator for this. The React Navigation docs explain how to do an authentication flow here:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

The example below is from their docs:

```js
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Implementation of HomeScreen, OtherScreen, SignInScreen, AuthLoadingScreen
// goes here.

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

Then you navigate doing something like this:

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
```